# mysqli_stmt::prepare() not working

Tags: php, mysql

First off, this is not a duplicate, as I have checked a number of other listings of this title and have got no working resolution as of yet.

This is my file, it is the functional part of a URL Shortener, completely hand-made from scratch by myself, so its gonna look messy.

```
<?php

class URLShortener
{
    protected $messages = Array();
    protected $db;
    protected $shorturl;
    protected $lurl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try 
        {
            $this -> dbConnect();
            if ($this -> validateInput())
            {
                $stmt = $this -> db -> prepare("INSERT INTO `redir` (`shorturl`, `longurl`, `disabled`, `aip`) VALUES (?,?,0,?);");
                $stmt -> bind_param('sss', $this -> shorturl, $_POST['longurl'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                $stmt -> execute();
                $this -> addMessage("Assigned a short url of ". $this -> shorturl .".",1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this -> addMessage($e -> getMessage(), 4);
        }
    }

    protected function validateInput()
    {
        if (empty($_POST['longurl']))
        {
            $this -> addMessage('Please enter a URL.', 2);
            $this -> lurl = true;
        }
        elseif (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$_POST['longurl']))
        {
            $this -> addMessage('Please enter a valid URL.');
            $this -> lurl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT `shorturl` FROM `redir` WHERE `longurl` =  ?;");
            $stmt -> bind_param('s', $_POST['longurl']);
            $stmt -> execute();
            //$stmt -> store_result();
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    $result = $stmt -> get_result(); // WHY DONT YOU EXIST?
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    $this -> addMessage($e -> getMessage(), 4);
                }
                if($result){
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
                    {
                        $this -> addMessage('This URL is already shortened to <a href="http://ndlee.com/'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</a>',3);
                        $this -> lurl = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($_POST['shorturl']))
        {
            $this -> shorturl = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$^",$_POST['shorturl']) AND strlen($_POST['shorturl']) > 20)
            {
                $this -> addMessage('Your custom URL contained illegal characters, or was too long. A random URL has been assigned instead.',2);
                $this -> shorturl = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                $this -> shorturl = $_POST['shorturl'];
            }
        }
        $stmt1 = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT `shorturl` FROM `redir` WHERE `shorturl` =  ?;");
        if( ! $stmt1 = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT `shorturl` FROM `redir` WHERE `shorturl` =  ?;"))
        {
            $this -> addMessage('Error: ' . $db->error,4);
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt1 -> bind_param('s', $this -> shorturl); // For some reason, this function doesn't exist. Yet it exists at line 44 and 18
            $stmt1 -> execute();
            //$stmt -> store_result();
            if ($stmt1->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $this -> addMessage('FATAL ERROR: We tried to assign you a random URL that was already assigned. This should never occur.',4);
                $this -> lurl = true;
            }
        }
        return empty($this -> lurl);
    }

    protected function dbConnect()
    {
        $this -> db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            throw new Exception("Database connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function addMessage($m, $l)
    {
        if(empty($l))
        {
            $l = 1;
        }
        $this -> messages[] = "<div align=\"center\" class=\"notice{$l}\"><div style=\"float:left;\"><img src=\"../images/{$l}.png\"></div> {$m}</div><br>";
        return true;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this -> messages;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this -> db -> close();
    }
}

class URLRetriever
{
    protected $messages = Array();
    protected $db;
    protected $lurl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this -> dbConnect();
            if ($this -> validateInput())
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM redir WHERE shorturl = {$_GET['u']};";
                $result=mysqli_query($this -> db, $sql);
                //$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($result)
                {
                    $fuckimtired = mysqli_fetch_all($result); // Yeah, just ignore this, I'm just suffering lack-of-energy-drink-itus.
                    foreach ($fuckimtired as $row)
                    {
                        print_r($row);
                        $header('location: '.$row['longurl']);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this -> addMessage("No such short URL. <a href=\"http://ndlee.com/\">Click here to return to NDLee.com</a>",4);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this -> addMessage($e -> getMessage(), 4);
        }
    }

    protected function validateInput()
    {
        if(empty($_GET['u']))
        {
            $this -> lurl = true;
            $this -> addMessage("FATAL EXCEPTION: NO URL",4);
        }
        return empty($this -> lurl);
    }

    protected function dbConnect()
    {
        //$this -> db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        //$this -> db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST .';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $this -> db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        return true;
    }

    protected function addMessage($m, $l)
    {
        if(empty($l))
        {
            $l = 1;
        }
        $this -> messages[] = "<div align=\"center\" class=\"notice{$l}\"><div style=\"float:left;\"><img src=\"../images/{$l}.png\"></div> {$m}</div><br>";
        return true;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this -> messages;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        //$this -> db -> close();
    }
}
?>
```

Bind param believes that its prepare statement isn't an object. Mind you, my bind params are all based off one another and if 2 work, the third must as well. Infact, Line 44's statement and Line 90's statement are identical, except instead of selecting by longurl, we are selecting by shorturl.

Line 18

```
$stmt -> bind_param('sss', $this -> shorturl, $_POST['longurl'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Line 44

```
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $_POST['longurl']);
```

Those two instances work. But when we get to line 90,

```
$stmt1 -> bind_param('s', $this -> shorturl); // For some reason, this function doesn't exist. Yet it exists at line 44 and 18
```

I was following an answer at [(Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921670/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object) to validate my prepare statement, and now instead of proceeding normally, it spits out a non-fatal handled error, and returns me to the index as if everything worked fine.

I've checked the sql database and the url is being saved regardless of this error, however I believe it is not being checked for duplicate entries of short urls.

[image: As you can see here, the script is saving urls fine. It just can't perform that added safety check]

Is there anything you guys can see that I can't?